# Unsure of score in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch in a seach engine that I have built. I am unsure about the scoring in Elasticsearch. See my code below

```
for(let i=0; i<lens; i++){
                        source = data[i]._source
                        src = source.src
                        alt = source.alt
                        desc = source.desc
                        score = data[i]._score
                        this.results.push({src: src, alt: alt, desc: desc, score: score})
```

Now this does bring back a result, but they are like 7.764. What does this value mean. Is it 7.764% ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch uses the [BM25 algorithm](https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-2-the-bm25-algorithm-and-its-variables) for scoring, and its not the % which you are guessing.

Apart from BM25 reading, you can also use the [explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) which explains how the score of each matching document is calculated.

Comment: I knew it was BM25, but I am still unsure. So what actually is the 7.764?

Comment: @thewal 7.764 is the score of your document which matched your search criteria, if you have other documents in your search results, those would be sorted in desc order of `_score`